# Class constructor super() doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, class, internet-explorer, babeljs

Today I found out the hard way that babel doesn't compile classes to work with IE. There's a [running babel issue here](https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/133). However I've tried a lot of the solutions in that issue with no luck.

My current `.babelrc` file looks like this.

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-regenerator",
    "syntax-async-functions"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-2"
  ]
}
```

I cant get something as simple as this running in IE.

```
class Main {
  constructor(props) {    
    console.log(props.apple)
  }
}

class Test extends Main {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(this.apple)
  }
}

new Test({apple: 'pie'})
```

I tested on IE10 (10.0.9200.17228) running from Windows 8.

Comment: You tried the es2015-loose preset?

Comment: Hey @elclanrs yep I have I replaced `es2015` with `es2015-loose` recompiled and the issue still happened.

Comment: Giving the Version[s] of IE always helps too

Comment: Also show us the transpiled code, and what errors IE throws. And make sure your page is not in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

`es2015-loose` works! I wasn't updating the babel configuration in my `webpack.config.js` I was updating it in my `.babelrc`.